# Trust self-signed certificate for Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS in perl

Tags: perl

Trying to use [Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS](https://metacpan.org/pod/Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS) for sending email. My transport is:

```
    my $transport = Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS->new({
            host => $smtpserver,
            ssl => 'starttls',
            sasl_username => $smtpuser,
            sasl_password => $smtppassword,
            debug => 1,
    });
```

When trying send the email, the debug says:

```
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f893b2b00f0)<<< 250-SIZE 52428800
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f893b2b00f0)<<< 250-8BITMIME
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f893b2b00f0)<<< 250-PIPELINING
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f893b2b00f0)<<< 250-STARTTLS
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f893b2b00f0)<<< 250 HELP
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f893b2b00f0)>>> STARTTLS
Net::SMTPS=GLOB(0x7f893b2b00f0)<<< 220 TLS go ahead
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:735: local error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
DEBUG: .../IO/Socket/SSL.pm:738: fatal SSL error: SSL connect attempt failed error:14090086:SSL routines:ssl3_get_server_certificate:certificate verify failed
unable to establish SMTP connection
```

Probably because the server using `self-signed` certificate. (When using the same setting in the Thunderbird it is needed to add the "trust this certificate" setting.)

The question is: How to add the "trust this certificate" for the `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS` - thus allow sending email.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no direct way to give  Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS SSL specific arguments. But, since ultimately [IO:Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL) is used you can hack your way around this limitation. From the man page:

> This is a list of typical errors seen with the use of IO::Socket::SSL:. ....
>
> - Make SSL settings inacessible by the user, together with bad builtin settings.
>
>   Some modules use IO::Socket::SSL, but don't make the SSL settings available to the user. This is often combined with bad builtin settings or defaults (like switching verification off). Thus the user needs to hack around these restrictions by using set_args_filter_hack or similar.

Thus what you could do is

```
IO::Socket::SSL::set_args_filter_hack( sub {
    my ($is_server,$args) = @_;
    $args->{SSL_fingerprint} = 'sha1$437104....'
});
```

With this option you could make certificate pinning trust a certificate as long as it's fingerprint matches the given one. You can get the fingerprint for instance with:

```
openssl s_client -connect mail.example.org:25 -starttls smtp  |\
 openssl x509 -fingerprint -noout
```

Alternative ways would be to use the certificate as trusted with the `SSL_ca_file` option. You could also set `SSL_verify_mode` to 0 (`SSL_VERFY_NONE`) but since this disables any kind of validation you should only use this for testing.

Please note that `set_args_filter_hack` is global, that is it affects all IO::Socket::SSL objects in your program. Thus depending on the program you should only set it directly before you establish the connection with Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS and reset it immediately afterwards.

For more information about these options please read the [documentation of IO::Socket::SSL](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Socket::SSL).

Comment: The `set_args_filter_hack` method `just works`. :) Easy to implement and allows only specific fingerprint. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can control the SSL usage with the options of new() constructor method

```
"SSL_verify_mode"=>'SSL_VERIFY_NONE'
```

IN Email/Sender/Transport/SMTPS.pm

```
  # compatible
  my $ssl = $self->ssl;
  $ssl = 'ssl' if $self->ssl and $self->ssl ne 'starttls';

  return (
    $self->host,
    Port    => $self->port,
    Timeout => $self->timeout,
    defined $ssl             ? (doSSL     => $ssl)             : (),
    defined $self->helo      ? (Hello     => $self->helo)      : (),
    defined $self->localaddr ? (LocalAddr => $self->localaddr) : (),
    defined $self->localport ? (LocalPort => $self->localport) : (),
    defined $self->debug     ? (Debug     => $self->debug) : (),
    "SSL_verify_mode"=>'SSL_VERIFY_NONE',#ADDED LINE
  );
```

EDIT: This is really bad, because as per comments you trust everything. Instead if on linux/*nix

```
  cat tobetrusted.crt >> /etc/ssl/cert.pem
```

Comment: Could you please add more info in the context of the question? How to use it with `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS`? (seems like the `Email::Sender::Transport::SMTPS` doesn't accepts the `SSL_verify_mod => 'SSL_VERIFY_NONE'`.

Comment: That would not trusting the certificate but disabling any kind of validation and thus implicitly trusting anything.

Comment: You can copy the cert to you trusted store on the client.